# How to include ToUpper() INSIDE query condition?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have this query that is supposed to get all results where active=TRUE in table, but i want to ensure if users lets say changed the active value in the Table to say "True" or "tRue" that the query recognizes it as intended TRUE, by somehow applying Uppercase ON the query condition all the time

```
$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [active] = 'TRUE'.ToUpper()"
write-host $Table += $row.Item("active")
```

Notice, this is what I have but of course, it throws error

```
WHERE [active] = 'TRUE'.ToUpper()"
```

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot call methods on varchar."

Comment: Does your collation on the SQL Server instance require case sensitivity? If not, this post is moot. Standard Latin-US collation will treat True=TRUE=tRue.

Comment: @dfundako i never set it that way so i dont think so. is there such option o:? saw your additional information, so thats what collation does...let me try including collation and see, much thanks!

Comment: Run a test and check. Open up SSMS or Powershell and run your query with a [active]='TrUe' and see if anything comes back.

Comment: @dfundako ok so Standard Latin-US is not valid collation its telling me. I need a collation that no matter what users enter for active in the table, i.e. trUE, or true, it automatically makes the values uppercase. I have tried this, but it doesnt seem to have an effect when i tried editting the column values (the values were confirmed the same way i entered them) Latin1_General_CS_AS

Comment: are you asking how to use the powershell toupper or the SQL one?

Comment: @ArcSet yes, my original question is as was posted, how to use the ToUpper INSDIE the query statement like i have in script. dfundako suggested collating the column instead, so if thats also an option i dont mind collating the column itself

Comment: Wait i see the question but are you asking hey how can i use ToUpper in powershell side or on the SQL server side

Comment: @ArcSet oh ok, i possibly misunderstood. yes, im trying to use it on sql side, since im attempting to use it inside the query statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default collation will provide the functionality you require (case-insensitive match) by default, however if you want to force an insensitive match if your collation is case sensitive then you can use `UPPER` function but be aware this will cause a full scan of your table (and can therefore have some major performance implications).

To check your current collation:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DbName', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

This will give you the collation, example `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Here `CI` means `Case Insensitive`

If you have this then you are good to go. If not you could do:

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE UPPER([active]) = 'TRUE'
```

But this will scan your whole table.

If you have the ability to change your schema you could force the collation for the column if you want:

```
CREATE TABLE [#CollationTest]
(
  [MyColumnName] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)  

INSERT INTO [#CollationTest] ([MyColumnName]) VALUES ('Value123')
INSERT INTO [#CollationTest] ([MyColumnName]) VALUES ('value123')


SELECT * FROM [#CollationTest] WHERE [MyColumnName] = 'value123' -- Returns 2 rows

DROP TABLE [#CollationTest]
```

Comment: oh so its UPPER instead. if you dont mind, can you tell me what AS means in the collation? also, thank you for the breakdown! really good answer. of course im considering performance as well but the query statement has to match that the active column value equals "TRUE", thats why i have to enforce the active column "True" values to automatically become TRUE otherwise the query will not match "True" or "tRue" with 'TRUE' condition

Comment: AS or AI mean Accent Sensitive or Accent Insensitive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017) 

It "Distinguishes between accented and unaccented characters. For example, 'a' is not equal to 'ấ'. If this option is not selected, the collation is accent-insensitive. That is, SQL Server considers the accented and unaccented versions of letters to be identical for sorting purposes. You can explicitly select accent insensitivity by specifying _AI".

Comment: oh i see! its to take into account accent scenarios like how some alphabets in french have ' on them for example.i got it. since you mentioned performance...the collation you provided "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" doesnt this mean that any value entered for active is confirmed as what is entered, since its Case-Insensitive (CI)? the query statement has to match that the active column value equals "TRUE", thats whyhave to enforce the active column "True" values to automatically become TRUE otherwise the query will not match "True" or "tRue" with 'TRUE' condition. im looking for upper collation

Comment: Case Insensitive means that it doesn't matter what you have in your query case wise, or what is in your table case wise. It means that no matter it will always be a match and be found, so True = TRue = TRUE = tRue, they are all the same. You therefore don't need to do any UPPPER conversions or anything in your query, just have active = 'true' (or any other style) and it will work.

Comment: ok so after searching for a while, there appears to be no UPPERCASE collation for columns in MSSQL. The only solution i found is to set it the way you specified "UPPER([active])". thats unfortunate. i was hoping to do this without affecting performance :/

Comment: we posted at the exact same time lol. i gotcha, thanks! I will try it now. btw, how can i check the collation of a specif column instead of the whole DB similar to the one you posted: SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DbName', 'Collation') SQLCollation;

Comment: No, you don't need an uppercase collation. You need a Case Insensitive collation, as you want to match no matter the casing of the column.

Comment: This will let you find the column column collation https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you very much!